# why my ajax code not run?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm just trying to check whether the username already exists, the basic idea is that when the form is sent,my ajax code will connect to checkUsername.php, and checkUsername.php will go to my database and check whether the username is already exists, and return a span.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "checkUsername.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {"usernameCheck": v1},  
      dataType:"text",
      success:function(data){
    alert("system avaliable!!"); 
    if($("#status-not-available").val(data) == "no"){
        $('#username').css({'border' : '4px solid red'});
        checkUsername = false;
    }
    else{
        $('#username').css({'border' : '4px solid white'});
    }
      },
      fail:function(data){
    alert("system not avaliable");  
      },
  });
```

**php:**

```
$database = new SQLite3('myDatabase.db');  //setup connection
$usernameCheck = $_POST['usernameCheck'];  //get the username they input
$stmt = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :usernameCheck");
$stmt->bindValue(':usernameCheck',$usernameCheck,SQLite3_TEXT);
$row = $stmt->execute()->fetchArray();

if(isset($row['username'])){
    echo "<span class='status-not-available'>no</span>";
}
else{
    echo "<span class='status-not-available'>yes</span>";
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors or something?

Comment: _Something_ must happen...?

Comment: What's `v1`? in the body of the request?

Comment: nothing happens...and no error, my web still can run, v1 is the username the user input

Comment: use `bindParams` instead

Answer (score 0):

Ajax's `dataType:"text"` means you want to return response as `text`.But you are returning `html` as response also this `html` is not loaded in `DOM` so that causes error.

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "checkUsername.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {"usernameCheck": v1},  
      dataType:"text",
      success:function(data){
    alert("system avaliable!!"); 
    if(data == "no"){
        $('#username').css({'border' : '4px solid red'});
        checkUsername = false;
    }
    else{
        $('#username').css({'border' : '4px solid white'});
    }
      },
      fail:function(data){
    alert("system not avaliable");  
      },
  });
```

**PHP**

```
$database = new SQLite3('myDatabase.db');  //setup connection
 $usernameCheck = $_POST['usernameCheck'];  //get the username they input
 $stmt = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :usernameCheck");
 $stmt->bindValue(':usernameCheck',$usernameCheck,SQLite3_TEXT);
 $row = $stmt->execute()->fetchArray();
 if(isset($row['username'])){
 echo "no";//just send response as text rather than html
 }
 else{
echo "yes";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not dom element with id `status-not-available`, its your ajax response and it is a string, So simply send only `yes` or `no` from ajax and accordingly

```
if(data == "no"){
```